# Change border of a single table cell element with border collapse

Tags: html, css

I want to make a table with several cells. The cells must have exactly an 1px border between them. This is why I'm using border-collapse: collapse.

When I :hover on a td element, I want it's (4 side) border to change it's color to red, but this the effects are not always visible.

Here is a demo of the problem, it should explain a lot:

http://jsfiddle.net/4444a/

I tried to mix position and z-index, but they did not work out well.

Is there any pure CSS way to do it efficiently?

"Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code" - HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    margin: 20px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}

td:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: The issue is that only some borders turn to red. The reason is that border resolution causes the borders other cells (cells to the left of and above the hovered cell) to “win” the red border.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inset would do the trick.  Change the  `td`  `border: 1px solid black;` to :

```
td {
  ...
  border: 1px inset black;
  ...    
 }
```

[Updated Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ANE6F/)

Comment: Nice trick. It fools the [border resolution](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#border-conflict-resolution) algorithm, since `solid` has priority over `inset`.

Comment: Opera seems to have some problems with this, but all other (major) browsers are fine. I guess I'll be usign this method. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry that i do not have enough reputation to comment so I post this as an answer.

I have set   tags as `inset black` then set the cell I need to change border color to `solid`, too.
But it seems I did wrongly somewhere.
Hope to be helped and thanks so much.

This is mine: http://jsfiddle.net/oLryckqn/